# Instagram API get bulk objects by comma separated IDs

Tags: endpoint, instagram-api, bulk

I have a simple application where I have a bulk Instagram object ids. I'm looking for an API, from where I can send the ids as a comma separated string or in a similar fashion and get a list of Instagram objects. I'm unable to find an endpoint in the official Instagram API.

I do not want to retrieve each object one by one as I require to retrieve a bulk data and retrieving one by one would be too time consuming, and would exhaust my resources.

A similar function in twitter can be found below

```
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup
```

I'm looking for a similar function for Instagram.
Is there a solution for this?

FYI i'm looking for another solution other than the Instagram endpoint - tags/hello/media/recent because I need information from multiple id's at the same time. Also the number of information retrieved by this endpoint is insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to get media data by id in bulk, you have to make 1 API call per id in a loop.

There is an API limit of 5000 calls/hour, so this may limit you based on the number of media items you want to retrieve.

You can use this API call in a loop to get media data by id:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

As krisrak said, there is no out-of-the-box API for this. You could create your own, but it would have to send each request separately as that is how Instagram has their API set up and there is NO way around this.